# When printing on Windows, the printer settings are not saved, they keep on being reseted (but not for all settings)

Tags: printing, lpr

While trying to *set* the settings for a printer, every time I go into the settings, apply them, press ok and then go back, I notice my settings are not saved. For example, the `Paper Source` keeps getting back to `Auto-Select`. If I set it on `Tray1` it is saved, but when I choose a more 'exotic' option, it doesn't.

[image: trying-to-set-paper-deck-settings]

[image: but-it-keeps-on-getting-to-default-value]

What could be the reason that this happens?

Comment: What is your printer model and what driver is installed for it?

Answer (score 0):

Your printer driver probably does not communicate with the printer and does not know which settings are allowed. You can check this in the printer driver. Go to the Printer, right-click on `Printer Preferences` and then click on the 'Printer' tab. You can see if the printer in the image matches the real printer, including all extra peripherals (e.g. extra paper-deck). Like this:

[image: printer-configuration]

Now the reason that this happens, is that you probably haven't set up the printer port properly. So you can print, but there is no two-way communication.

Check the port settings, you should not use the `raw` protocol, but the `LPR` protocol and you should give a queue name, e.g. 'print', 'direct' or 'hold'.

⬇︎ Here the wrong setting ⬇︎

[image: example-wrong-setting]

⬇︎ Here the correct setting ⬇︎

[image: example-right-LPR-setting]

So your computer/printer-driver has no clue that these extra peripherals are installed, and you are only to set values that are part of the standard 'simple' configuration. Other 'exotic' settings are not honoured as long your computer/printer-driver does not know about these extra peripherals. I have seen other printer-drivers where you can manage this manually, but best is of course if there is a two-way communication between the computer/printer-driver and the printer (or Fiery Print controller).